# Flutter: Press button animation goes behind the container that the button is inside

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I am learning flutter and stumbled upon the button press animation is showing behind the container its inside. I was following this guide: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DNCV1K5eVMw.

Tried to see if I could add elevation to the container but no. Any ideas?

[image]

The shown image shows me click on the left home icon. The "round" grey thing behind the container is the default google/flutter button press animation. Why would it be displayed behind the container of which the button is inside?

Code:

```
class NavigationBar extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      color: bodyColor,
      height: 70,
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10, bottom: 30),
      child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
        children: <Widget>[
          IconButton(
            icon: Icon(
              Icons.home,
              size: 35,
            ),
            onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context)
                .pushNamed('/accountpage', arguments: 'Data from first page'),
          ),
          IconButton(
            icon: Icon(
              Icons.home,
              size: 35,
            ),
            onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context)
                .pushNamed('/second', arguments: 'Data from seoncd page'),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not exactly sure why this is happening, but two ways that I know on how to get around this is by 1. actually using the *BottomNavigationBar* https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/BottomNavigationBar-class.html Widget that it was meant for, but if you want to keep your custom bottomBar then you can 2. Wrap the icons in a *Material* Widget https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Material-class.html
You are going to need to dabble with the padding to make the icons visible, but I just commented it out.

```
 Container(
        color: Colors.bodyColor,
        height: 70,
        // padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10, bottom: 30),
        child: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
          children: <Widget>[
            Material(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12), // Can change it to your own liking or remove it
              color: Colors.transparent,
              child: IconButton(
                icon: Icon(
                  Icons.home,
                  size: 35,
                ),
                onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('/accountpage',
                    arguments: 'Data from first page'),
              ),
            ),
            Material(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
              color: Colors.transparent,
              child: IconButton(
                icon: Icon(
                  Icons.home,
                  size: 35,
                ),
                onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('/accountpage',
                    arguments: 'Data from first page'),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
```

Comment: Sorry for the late comment. Tried what you told me and it worked kinda. Animation would display in at the correct position but something was just off with it. I did however go with the second option (To use the default bottom nav) and after a day of work I've kind of mastered that and states. Thank you :)